# Open Source web based Screen Sharing

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, screensharing

Is there any open source screen sharing (or desktop sharing) software that I can use to integrate into my web site? Any flash/java based solutions?

Comment: By 'open source' do you actually mean 'free'?  The two are not the same.  If not, what is your budget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash does not have public / documented APIs to make this work.  Adobe Connect even needs an additional plugin for screen sharing.

I believe Adobe has been working on APIs to help make screen sharing a reality.  I believe such features were rolled into [LiveCycle Collaboration Service](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/services/collaboration.html); however I thought that was only available as a hosted service.  [And I don't see the screen sharing feature documented on that page].  Here is [more info](http://blogs.adobe.com/collabmethods/2010/08/screen-sharing-and-recording-august-feature-tsunami.html) from when the feature was announced; it also confirms that this is part of LCCS.

Beyond that, you can look at [some tools like these](http://avchathq.com/blog/screen-sharing-in-flash-video-chat-applications/), which allow you to broadcast your web cam feed.  And then tie them into something like Flash Media Server or Red5 to stream that out to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

[BigBlueButton](http://www.bigbluebutton.org/) is an open Java based web conferencing software.

Answer (score 1):

It's not open source, but I have had many very favorable reviews on [XSplit](http://www.xsplit.com/download/).

As for integrating a flash/java app on your site, I would actually recommend just streaming your screen to a site such as [Justin.tv](http://www.justin.tv). [Here's](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=195391) a good guide on how to set up XSplit and start streaming to justin.tv. (I am into the video game starcraft and the streaming scene behind it)

From there, you just have to embed it on your site. No server-side stuff needed!

Hope this helped, and good luck!